# How to implement Component mapping in hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

Hi here iam trying to convert my hbm file mapping to hibernate annotations here i have found tag like

```
<component name="timeSlot" class="model.calendar.TimeSlot">
  <property name="startTime" column="app_start_time" />
  <property name="endTime" column="app_end_time" />
</component>
```

in `appointment.hbm.xml` file.

And my modal class for `appointment.java` is like

```
public class Appointment extends BaseDo implements Delivery {
  private TimeSlot timeSlot;       
}
```

And my `timeslot.java` modal looks like

```
public class TimeSlot extends BaseDo {

  Date startTime;
  Date endTime;
}
```

So here i don't understand how to annotate Timeslot in appointment.java i have searched and i understood that i need to use `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable` tags but not sure how to use that can anyone suggest me in doing this.

Comment: This is very straightforward in the hibernate docs. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-component

Comment: Even i have separate table for timeslot modal class here i cant use the reference you have provided ,Your reference is useful when the attributes of time slot are also present in appointment table but it is not in my case @Taylor

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
public class Appointment extends BaseDo implements Delivery {
    private TimeSlot timeSlot;   

    @Embedded
    public TimeSlot getTimeSlot() {
        return timeSlot;
    }

    public void setTimeSlot (TimeSlot timeSlot) {
        this.timeSlot= timeSlot;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class TimeSlot extends BaseDo {

  Date startTime;
  Date endTime;

  @Column 
  public Date getStartTime(){
      return startTime
  }

  public void setStartTime(Date startTime){
      this.startTime = startTime;
  } 

  @Column 
  public Date getEndTime(){
      return endTime
  }

  public void setEndTime(Date endTime){
      this.endTime = endTime;
  } 

}
```